Change Theme with a button - python Tkinter
I'm trying to have a program change from light to dark mode with a check button but it does not change the theme
import tkinter as tk 
import ttkbootstrap as ttk

#setup
window = ttk.Window(themename = "flatly")
window.title("Buttons")
window.geometry('600x400')

#dark mode
check_var = tk.StringVar()
check = ttk.Checkbutton(
    window, 
    text= "Dark mode",
    command= lambda: print(check_var.get()),
    variable= check_var)
check.pack()

if check_var == 1:
    window = ttk.Window(themename = "darkly")
if check_var == 0:
    window = ttk.Window(themename = "flatly")
    
#run
window.mainloop()

I want the theme to go from to light to dark when the check button is pressed

You need to create function of Checkbutton class. We can set variable, style and command.
snippet:
check = ttk.Checkbutton(
    window, 
    text= "Dark mode",
    command= lambda:toggle_theme(check_var),
    variable= check_var,
    style='custom.TCcheckbutton')
check.pack()


def toggle_theme(check_var):
    try:
        if check_var.get():
            ttk.Window(themename = "darkly")
        else:
            ttk.Window(themename = "flatly")
    except:
        pass 


You need to check the state of the checkbutton inside the callback of command option instead of after creating the checkbutton.  Also you need to use theme_use() of Style object (window.style) to change theme:
...

def change_theme():
    theme = 'darkly' if check_var.get() == '1' else 'flatly'
    window.style.theme_use(theme)

...
check = ttk.Checkbutton(
    window,
    text="Dark mode",
    command=change_theme,
    variable=check_var)
...


You want to change theme of the same window and not to open a new window with different theme. So,

use ttk.Style().theme_use("<theme_name>").

use IntVar() instead of StringVar() as IntVar has only two states 0 and 1.

Use a separate function and change the theme using ttk.Style().theme_use("<theme_name>")

add variable= int_variable_name as an argument of the widget Checkbutton
import tkinter as tk 
import ttkbootstrap as ttk

def change_theme(): # use function
    check_state = check_var.get()
    if check_state == 1:
        style.theme_use("darkly") # use style.theme_use
    else:
        style.theme_use(themename = "flatly") 


#setup
window = ttk.Window("flatly")
window.title("Buttons")
window.geometry('600x400')

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("flatly") # use style.theme_use

check_var = tk.IntVar() # use IntVar

check  = tk.Checkbutton(window, 
    text= "Dark mode",
    variable=check_var,
    command = change_theme) # use variable = check_var as an argument

check.pack()

window.mainloop()



`
